# Android Studio debugger launches with null intent

Tags: debugging, android-intent, android-studio

When I try to debug my application in the brand new Android Studio, something strange happens: Instead of the intent action set in the androidManifest (android.intent.action.MAIN) it launches with a null intent.
I had to add a catcher in the intent filter to replace null intents with "android.intent.action.MAIN" but surely this isn't the right way to do it.
Launching the app directly from the launcher, of course, doesn't cause this. Only the debugger launch, for some strange reason.
I couldn't find a setting for setting an intent to launch - what am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug that has been fixed (https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/58940/) for version 0.1.1

Comment: Can't wait for it to be downloadable. Thanks for the heads up.